# How do I make a custom widget in WebOS?

Tags: webos, palm

I'm new to Palm WebOS development and can't figure out how to create a custom widget.

Does anyone know of a really simple step-by-step walk-through for noobs?

Palm's explanation [here](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1884&Itemid=56&limitstart=4) isn't all that helpful. For example it tells me the HTML is optional so I can have just javascript (but I don't know what sort of javascript I should put there or when it should run). Also it says to add the widget to sources.json "in the standard Mojo way" (I don't know what this way is - my sources.json contains only scenes and assistants so I don't know what a widget should look like in here).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.